# HOW to build a system which allows a user to submit jobs to a queue

Tags: python, networking, queue, system, jobs

Using a combination of C, C++, Shell, Perl and/or Python I want to develop a system which allows a user to submit jobs to a queue (or queues). Jobs from the queue should be executed on one of a number of worker machines in an appropriate order.

The system should provide basic functionality. However in addition you may consider one or more of the following specific problems in more detail:

```
Support for multiple users
Flexible specification of jobs
Interdependencies between jobs
Integration of job creation with existing package(s)
Cancelling Jobs
Smarter scheduling of jobs
Discovery of available machines
Varying capabilities of worker nodes
Multiple Operating Systems
Failure of worker hardware
Failure of the Job Execution(including hanging indefinitely)
Failure of the queue management machine(s).
```

I have some basic experience in C, C++ and mostly in Python. I am interested in providing basic functionality using this system. There is mainly theory on internet about all these but I can't find examples so as to see how it works. If anyone has info, sources, example code or anything which can help me I will really apreciate it.

Comment: there are many such frameworks already in existence

Answer (score 3):

Why do you try to reinvent wheels?

Use http://celeryproject.org/

Comment: I am complete understand what your point but its a project that I have to do it. Tt does not need to be something perfect just have the basic factionalities, very basic. I am going to give a look this software and its code. Thanks for the link.